# Unsure about website address structure

Tags: html, web, ip-address

In my websites normally I use Ajax, so the address is always something like

`www.xxx.com` for all pages.

But now I read and search in google and I cant understand how is made this type of site:

```
https://welshare.com/login

https://welshare.com/signup
```

If I change the address bar to login.php or asp or html the page gives an error.

So my question is, how I can make something like that? is it htaccess? 
what is the login? a new page? a module?

Comment: the welshare is only an example, the question is general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using apache as your server, you'll want to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). IIS also has an extension for this called [URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).

**Edit**
To elaborate on how it works: Once you have your rules set up, it will look at the requested URL (say, `mysite.com/test`) and then on the server side, actually send a request to `mysite.com/index.php?page=test`. Whatever the output of the request is will be sent back to the user's browser and they will have no idea that that's actually the page that was requested.

Comment: but, you confirm, is a new page? the login and signup? like login.php, and the extension is omitted?

Comment: @user455318: You have control over how the rewrite rule is set up, if you want it to show `login.php` or `index.php?page=login`, you can do either (or both) with the rules you set up. See my edit for essentially how it works.

Comment: @user455318: To directly answer your question, it could be to `login.php` or it could be to any other configuration that works for the site as in my examples above.

Answer (score 0):

[mod_rewrite](http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) is the way to go. For a very easy to use tutorial click the link.

What is does in a nutshell is take a URL like *http://www.example.com/index.asp?page=login* and with the right parameters, transforms it into *http://www.example.com/login*